# Get Month from Date Not Returning Text from all cells - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

[image]

I used =TEXT(K2,"mmmm") and only some of the cells return a month. I formatted Column K as a date. Some of the cells in Column K appear to have different indentation. Any ideas?

Comment: The month() function? instead of the text() function.

Comment: Recheck those dates. Most of them are text. May even be that those that actually are dates return unexpected results too.

Comment: This has been discussed ad nauseum.  You need to "back up" and **IMPORT** your dates, telling Excel, **at the time of import**, that the dates in the file are in MDY format. *Your cells where you get a result are incorrect anyway*.

Comment: Like Ron Rosenfeld explains your example returns August for 02/08/2019 while I would expect that to be February (seeing the date notation  of the cells further on). So your dates are not formatted correctly and Excel will see all dates with day higher then 12 as text (because there's no month 12+).